# Start downloading excel eagerly

Tags: java, excel, rest, apache-poi

I need to start the download immediately. The processing takes around 5 minutes in total. So, want to start download immediately (Its fine if it takes time once it gets started). I DON'T want to do it in asynchronous way i.e. notify the user once it gets completed kind of logic. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
@GET
@Path("/download")
@Produces("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
public void downloadExcel(@Context HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"sample.xlsx\"");

    SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook();
    SXXFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
    SXSSFRow row = sheet.create(row)
    for (String column: headers) {
        // create cell and write in cell
    }


    ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

    /** this is the problem. it closes the output stream */
    wb.write(os);
    os.flush();

    for (batch i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        //get first batch of data takes around 45 sec
        List<?> data = someService.get(i);
        //create additional rows and write into wb 
        wb.write(os);
    }
    os.close();
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot do this. A `*.xlsx` file is a `ZIP` archive containing `XML` files and other files like pictures and so on. `Workbook.write` will write this `ZIP` archive to the `OutputStream`. If written once, the `ZIP` will contain the `Workbook`'s content at this time. So if you really write multiple times using `Workbook.write`, each time a `ZIP` archive containing a complete `Workbook` is written to the `OutputStream`. You cannot write portions of a `Workbook`.

Comment: @AxelRichter You could put that into an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I got that workbook.write is not going to do. Is there any other start downloading immediately (any thing/any way to serve my purpose). Thanks